# Can we use a camera with a frame rate of 1 trillion FPS to observe electrons, protons, and neutrons?

Tags: atoms, subatomic

Like with this camera from MIT that works at 1 trillion FPS: https://youtu.be/EtsXgODHMWk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The wavelength of visible light is too long to resolve individual subatomic particles, so even if you had an extremely fast shutter on your camera, the particles would remain invisible.

Particle accelerators use detectors that can capture extremely fast events occurring on extremely small length scales, but they do not use visible light to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The MIT camera is neat, but based on a photography trick. To make the video you are not seeing the same photons from to frame, you are seeing a very short burst of light and only a proportion of photons make it to the camera which has complex shutter timing relationship with the laser.  This is repeated as the the laser line is swept over the object.  Can you catch enough photons bouncing off a single atomic particle, not likely.  Maybe only one or 2 and then there are many losses on the way to the final image sensor chip.  The chip pixel would show a spot but not much more info than this.